# bash : add lines after string match

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

In one script sh file these lines are present.  I know we can do it using sed, but please let me know the way. I can use any suitable command.

BEFORE:

```
export HOME=${INSTALLROOT}/Subsystem

cd ${INSTALLROOT}
```

AFTER:

I want to add few lines after this string matches - export ASE_HOME

```
export HOME=${INSTALLROOT}/Subsystem


cd ${HOME}/tmp # added

rm -rf packed* # added


cd ${INSTALLROOT}
```

Comment: So you want to add two lines of script to an existing script?  Why don't you want to use `sed` for this?

Comment: THe single command `rm -rf ${HOME}/tmp/packed*` would be the idiomatic way to do that, though.  You rarely need `cd` in scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed '/export HOME=/a cd ${HOME}/tmp # added \n rm -rf packed* # added' yourfile
```

man `sed`:

```
a \ 
    text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.
```